# How to do AWS Batch with large deployments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-ec2, deployment, aws-batch

We're about to build out our backend platform, which involves processing data with various potentially huge ML models in a python environment.

Based on the AWS Batch docs I've read so far, it always creates new EC2 instances to process jobs: this also means that any code / models we need for processing have to be deployed for each job. I already had concerns with just the conda deployment (even on my local powerful machine it occasionally takes *hours* for some reason), but what if we have ML models that are several gigabytes in size? Both the time to deploy would be huge, plus we'd be potentially paying extra data egress fees for re-downloading the models each time.

**Is there a way to use only pre-existing EC2 instances that batch would just turn on / turn off when there are jobs to process?**

Alternatively, is there a way to mount a "virtual disk" to these EC2s that already has everything we want deployed on it? (I came across some Amazon EFS docs that suggest this might be possible, what's unclear to me if we can run code from there.)

If there is an alternative AWS service that'd be more ideal for our use-case that I'm not aware of, feel free to let me know; but our use-case just screams "batch processing" to me.

Comment: You are a seasoned SO user, and you are expected to know by now that this question is inappropriate for SO in just too many ways: #3 asks for recommendations, which is explicitly off-topic here; the other two questions are actually not about programming but about system administration, and they are again off-topic; last but not least, asking such multiple questions in a single post makes the post closable as "needs focus".

Comment: The #aws-batch tag doesn't even exist on other stack sites, which indicates to me that I am asking this in the place where everyone else does. I reformatted the rest to indicate what my priority ask is. (And as a seasoned SO user, comments like  why new people say this site is unapproachable or highly unfriendly, just my 2c.)

Comment: The problem was mostly the style and tone of the comment, I think it could've been phrased in a better way. And no, I'm not new - I'm saying it is the kind of comment that turns away new people.

Comment: From my side, the comment was written with a *neutral* tone intended, provided that I was talking to a seasoned user who is supposedly already familiar with do's and dont's here, and there is little room for hurt feelings; but interestingly enough, you did not complain *directly*, you only supposed that this is how we address new users (rest assured, we don't). Could I have prepended it with "*Kindly notice*" or something? Probably yes, but what would be the difference?

Comment: BTW and FWIW, you have not actually improved the question - you just turned the bullets into paragraphs; still many questions packed into one, not about programming, and asking for recommendations. Very *kind* of you... :(

Comment: I don't think it matters who we're addressing. If a new user searches for something and sees this, it has the same effect: turning them away from joining or asking questions. With that said, I do apologize, I think I've assumed it to be of a harsher tone than intended. 

And speaking of intentions: I have one main question, and then I shared things I am also considering as potential solutions - just as I would if I'd be trying to debug something. I cross-posted to serverfault too, but as I mentioned there isn't even a batch tag there, there are so few discussions taking place.

Comment: Appreciate the apology; but please see [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) (tl;dr: no)

Comment: Removed the serverfault one :)